# Import datatype DECIMAL from CSV to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, sqldatatypes

When importing a file.csv to sql server 2008 I am getting a problem.

In my file.csv the decimal is written in this way: (ex. 1234,34112) and It seems that SQL server does not understand the ',' as decimal.

My solution has been to import it using BULK INSERT as VARCHAR and after that convert it to decimal. It works but I guess it may be a better solution which I am not able to get.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not confident enough for an answer but perhaps BCP with -R switch which will work with your regional settings. BCP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: Personally, I almost always load data into character staging tables and then do conversions within the database.  I've found that it makes debugging much easier and generally speeds up the process of bringing data in.  So, your approach is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways of doing it one you have already mentioned importing in Sql server and then doing something like this..

```
CREATE Table ImportTable (Value NVARCHAR(1000))   --<-- Import the data as it is
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('1234,34112'),('12651635,68466'),('1234574,5874')

  /* Alter table add column of NUMERIC type.
     And update that column something like this... 
   */

UPDATE ImportTable 
SET NewColumn =  CAST(REPLACE(Value , ',', '.') AS NUMERIC(28,8))
```

Or you can change it your excel sheet before you import it.

Unless you are using SSIS to import data it is always best to get your data in Sql Server 1st using lose datatypes and then do any data manipulation if needed.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server Management Studio 17 provides a new direct option to import flat files that handles import of decimal csv columns for you. Right your database, then click Tasks > Import Flat File...